# Websockets not working properly on tomcat8 server

Tags: java, websocket, tomcat8, java-websocket

Below are the two scenarios that I am trying.

1. I have deployed application on server(tomcat8) using eclipse IDE. and then connecting the client with server using websocket protocol. It is working fine.
2. I have installed tomcat8 on a server machine, deployed the application and then connecting the client with server using websocket protocol. Then I am getting 404 not found error.

also If I run any jsp file on server using http protocol then it is working properly.

can anybody tell what I need to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Well start with the simplest possibility: perhaps websocket support is disabled in the production server. http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp , https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55855

Comment: what is the `ws` url that you are trying to connect and what is your config?

Comment: Websockets always have a problem with tomcat. We experienced it no matter the version of tomcat. If you really want to use tomcat, consider shifting to Jetty or something.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?